# Gmail consider email as spam

Tags: php, email, gmail, gmail-api, spam

I have setup a local windoes server on which I am running php cron job which send email to gmail on daily basic but after some time gmail consider this server as spam and not deliver any email to mail id.

I am using smtp virtual server on IIS6. I got respond as blow from GMIAL

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;name@mycompany.com

Action: failed

Status: 5.5.0

Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-5.7.1 [111.93.202.11012] 

Our system has detected that this message is

550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,

550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked.
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons why a email is considered spam. The most common (in my opinion!) are:

- Empty subject
- Mailbody containing suspicious words and text phrases
- Attachments are checked and considered "evil-ish"
- The mail sender (respectively the mail relay) is listed on a blacklist
  (e.g. because it sent too many mails in the past time).

See this troubleshooting page (or the related ones) from google can help you to solve the problems:
https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2696779

If you still cant find the error you can try to reach out for the google tech support. Maybe they can give you a more detailed description why the mails are blocked.